# Sencha touch Theming a specific Container in scss

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I wanted to know how to theme a specific Container and not every Container in the whole app.

```
#ext-element-18 x-scroll-container
```

if I wanted to change a background color of this would it be?

**app.scss**

```
#ext-element-18 x-scroll-container{
  background-color: #000;
}
```

this is not working

Comment: It's because your forgot the . before x-scroll-container, but see my answer for best practices

Answer (score 2):

It's bad pratice to base your CSS on auto-generated id's like `ext-element-18`. It can change anytime. So what I suggest is you use the [`cls` config](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-cls)

Give a **cls** attribute to your contrainer :

```
cls:'my-css-class'
```

Then use this class in your CSS or SCSS file to customize the component.

If you ever need to reach children of your component you can now do something like

```
.my-css-class .x-scroll-container{
  // custom style
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works too;

```
Ext.get(Ext.fly('ext-groepen_detail-1').query('.x-scroll-container')).elements[0].style.backgroundImage = 'url("http://somedomain/path/to/test logo 2.jpg")';
```